# Development guide for ver 2.2 specifically

Tags: android

I own a HTC Desire running 2.2 and I have decided to have some fun with programming apps for it. Some time back I had read an brief intro about Android at developer.android.com but because I wasn't too keen back then I just had it at the back of my mind.

However, when I visited today, I see the tutorial upgraded to higher versions since 2.2. I guess stuff explained there won't work on 2.2. As I mentioned, I will be writing my apps for 2.2 and nothing else. So I didn't find it useful to continue reading it.

Where can I find development guide for 2.2 specifically?  Googling didn't help me at all.

Also, I am not too keen on upgrading to any new version (I don't know if Desire would support them seamlessly anyway).

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that if you're just starting out and are looking for basic tutorials, it won't really make any difference if the tutorial is a bit newer since the basic stuff doesn't change. 
And looking at the tutorials on the [dev site](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial), it seems like the only one that needs a specific version still only demands 1.5.

The [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) might discuss features that aren't supported by 2.2 but the first few chapters should be pretty much the same, and you can easily tell if anything discussed is supported by 2.2 or not by clicking on the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) for the `Package`\ `Class` \etc and look up in the right corner of the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) to check that it's been there [since 8](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html) or earlier. If you're looking at the reference you can also tell it to filter by version 8 to only see what's supported by 2.2.

Comment: +1.  You can also look at the new 2.3+ features ([overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html)) to figure out what you can't do on 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a Gingerbread/2.3.3 upgrade for the HTC Desire now... info at http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=225607660802056 and download at http://developer.htc.com So might be worth looking at that and using a 2.3 guide...